# Taking the response of JSON and showing it in a textField

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

This function will upload a photo to a bucket and then show a direct link to that photo in a text field. What I wanted to do is to shorten the link, so I created a post request to Google's URL shortener using alamofire, and it worked, but I'm I don't know how to show it in a textfield.

Here is the function

```
func ImageDownloader(){


    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let imageContained = viewimage.image

    let storage = Storage.storage()
    var storageRef = storage.reference()
    storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "") // Link to bucket

    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageContained!, 0.8)! as NSData
    let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    let imageName = dateFormat.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
    let imagePath = "images/\(imageName).jpg"
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    let mountainsRef = storageRef.child(imagePath).putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }else{
            //store downloadURL
            let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
            self.getLink.text = downloadURL



                struct dlink {
                    let longLink: String
                }
                let v = dlink(longLink: "\(downloadURL)")

                let parameters = ["longUrl":"\(v.longLink)","MYURL":""]

                Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MY_KEY", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                }


            }
        metaData?.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        }
```

and here is the JSON response showing that it works fine.

[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `result.value` of `response` to get your serialized `JSON` response.

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MY_KEY", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
     if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
         //Now subscript on dictionary with keys to get your values.
         let id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? "DefaultValue" //set default value that you want
         let kind = dictionary["kind"] as? String ?? "DV"
         let longUrl = dictionary["longUrl"] as? String ?? "DV"
         print(id, kind, longUrl)
     }
}
```

You can check [`Response Handling`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-handling) section of `Alamofire` docs to get more idea.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JSONSerialization to parse the data:

```
let text = "{\"id\":\"https://link.right.here/\"}"

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: text.data(using: .ascii)!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
    let id = json["id"] as? String
    print(id)
} catch {
    print("Json parse failure")
    fatalError()
}
```

(Don't forget to save the `id` variable globally, or at least outside of that do/catch statement)

Then you will need to access the textfield that is changing. To do this you should make an outlet for the textfield in the storyboard that connects to the view controller. I won't go into this, because it is not what your question is asking for and because there are many tutorials out there regarding it. The key work is outlet.

Assuming the name of the outlet is `myTextfield`, simply for example, your code should look like this:

```
self.myTextfield.text = "\(id)"
```

where `id` is the variable that was set in the first part of code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. There is one thing that I did not understand. On the constant text contains a link what's the link that should be inserted there?

Comment: I wrote pseudo data as JSON, use your JSON instead